# Filtering based on the "rows" data after creating a pivot table in python pandas

Tags: python, indexing, pandas, dataframe

I have a set of data that I'm getting from a SQL database and reading into a pandas dataframe. The resulting df is about 250M rows and growing everyday. Therefore, I'd like to pivot the table to give me a much much smaller table to work with (few thousand rows).

The table looks something like this but much bigger:

```
data

  report_date             item_id        views   category
0  2013-06-01                   2            3          a
1  2013-06-01                   2            2          b
2  2013-06-01                   5           16          a 
3  2013-06-01                   2            4          c
4  2013-06-01                   2            5          d
```

I'd like to make this much smaller by ignoring the "category" column and just getting a total for views by date and item_id.

I'm doing this:

```
pivot = data.pivot_table(values=['views'], rows=['report_date','item_id'], aggfunc='sum')

                                 views  
report_date item_id
2013-06-01        2                 14           
2013-06-01        5                 16
```

Now imagine this is much bigger with the data range going for months and thousands of item_id's. I'd like to select the total views for item_id = 2 and report_date between '2013-06-01' and '2013-06-10' or something along those lines.

I've searched for several hours straight but I can't see how to select and/or filter off of values in my "rows" (i.e. report_date and item_id) section. I can only filter/select data in the "values" section (ex: views). This question is similar, and at the very end the asker commented the same question I'm asking but was never answered. I just wanted to try and draw attention to it.

[Filtering and selecting from pivot tables made with python pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11973741/filtering-and-selecting-from-pivot-tables-made-with-python-pandas#comment15988997_11976153)

I appreciated all the help. This site and the community have been absolutely invaluable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to slice it like so:

```
In [11]: pivot.ix[('2013-06-01', 3):('2013-06-01', 6)]
Out[11]:
                     views
report_date item_id
2013-06-01  5           16
```

*See [advance indexing in the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#advanced-indexing-with-hierarchical-index).*

Comment: Although, [something](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/3843) is fishy is going on with this particular example...