# Pandas filter pivot table by value

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

This might be a duplicate of [Pandas: Filtering pivot table rows where count is fewer than specified value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17109419/pandas-filtering-pivot-table-rows-where-count-is-fewer-than-specified-value) but I keep getting a `NaN` error

I have a data frame (df) of orders, order values, customer Id and dates:

```
id, date, order_count, daily_order_value
```

I want to view the total spend of guests who order more than once, three  and ten times over the duration.

```
Pnon_merch = pivot_table(dffilter, index =["guest_id"],
                         values=['ct_order','order_value'],
                         aggfunc= {'ct_order':np.sum,
                                   'order_value': [np.sum, np.mean]})
```

Printing `Pnon_merch`:

```
                 ct_order order_value          
                  sum   mean        sum
guest_id                               
  4813            1     2020.6400   2020.64
```

Produces a table, but when I try:

```
Pnon_merch_is1 = Pnon_merch[Pnon_merch["ct_order"]==1]
```

I get a list of `NaN`,

```
               ct_order order_value          
                  sum    mean  sum
guest_id                               
  4813            NaN    NaN   NaN


truefalse = [Pnon_merch["ct_order"]==1]
```

Gives a list of `True` / `False`

```
              sum
guest_id       
    4813       True
    6517       True
    7876      False
```

Why can the `True`/`false`, be returning `NaN`?

This example [Filtering based on the "rows" data after creating a pivot table in python pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17035108/filtering-based-on-the-rows-data-after-creating-a-pivot-table-in-python-pandas) seems to only filter on the index NOT the values.

(`groupby level = 0` does not yield the correct results either)

Comment: Is it because your `daily order_value` is missing an underscore?

Comment: updated with your edits and suggestions @johnE , Thanks for taking the time

Comment: Right, but I mean at the very top, it's nice to have code to construct the original df (or a small approximation).  Otherwise no one can test their code to see if it works unless they create a sample dataframe which might not have the same problem you are having.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First i would rename columns (after aggregation) like that:

```
Pnon_merch.columns = ['ct_order_sum','order_value_mean','order_value_sum']
```

now you can simply do this:

```
Pnon_merch_is1 = Pnon_merch[Pnon_merch["ct_order_sum"]==1]
```

Comment: @conr404, glad i could help :)

Comment: A possible reason you get NAs for Pnon_merch[Pnon_merch["ct_order"]==1] is that you are working with a multi-index. Try using Pnon_merch[Pnon_merch[('ct_order', 'sum')]==1].